# How to calculate the total number of characters in a 2D String array using enhanced for loop in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

```
public class LoopPractice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] wordData = {{"study", "consider", "examine", "learn"}, {"ponder", "read", "think", "cogigate"}};
        
        // Below is the question. Am trying to print the total number of characters in the wordData String array.

        //Use nested enhanced for loops to calculate the total number of characters in the wordData 2D array and print the result to the console. (Get the string .length() of each element)
```

// Below is what I have but it keeps printing the characterCount of 0 and the total number of each word character in the console.
// I don't know how to get the String.length() of the nested String array using the enhanced for loop.

```
        int characterCount = 0;
    for(String[] characters: wordData) {
      for(String totalNumber : characters) {
       System.out.println(totalNumber.length();
       }
    }
        System.out.println(characterCount);
        

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, except instead of printing to the console in the nested for loop, you need to add the length of the string to your characterCount. so you would do:

```
characterCount = characterCount + totalNumber.length();
```

or for short

```
characterCount += totalNumber.length();
```

You could write it a little cleaner:

```
int count = 0;

for (String[] arr: wordData) {
    for (String str: arr) {
        count += str.length();
    }
}

System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

While your code correctly iterates through the 2D array, you aren't actually incrementing your total character count.

Simply change the following line:

```
   System.out.println(totalNumber.length();
```

to:

```
characterCount+= totalNumber.length();
```

Answer (score -1):

int characterCount = 0;

for (String[] wordRow : wordData) {
`enter code here`for (String word: wordRow) {
`enter code here`characterCount += word.length();
}
}

System.out.println(characterCount);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).